# ASP.NET httpRedirect : redirect all pages except one

Tags: asp.net, web-config, http-redirect

I use this code in the web.config in one of the folders of my website to redirect all pages to the root because I want to close permanently this section.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <location>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.example.com/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

But I need to make an exception to this rule : I don't want my page "default.aspx" to be redirect. How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can add a wildcard in the following manner, to redirect only certain files:

```
    <configuration>
       <system.webServer>
          <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
             <add wildcard="*.php" destination="/default.htm" />
          </httpRedirect>
       </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

But i'm not sure if you can negate that, so that it ignores a certain file.

Answer (score 44):

Put your Default.aspx as `<location>` with disabled httpRedirect. It doesn't matter if you put `<location>` before or after `<system.webServer>`.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.example.com/" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
    <location path="Default.aspx">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="false" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```