# Setting up redirect in web.config file

Tags: asp.net, web-config, http-redirect

I'm trying to redirect some unfriendly URLs with more descriptive ones. These URLs end in `.aspx?cid=3916` with the last digits being different for each category name page. I want it to instead redirect to `Category/CategoryName/3916`. I tried this in the `web.config` file:

```
<location path="Category.aspx?cid=3916">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.example.com/Category/CategoryName/3916" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

but since it didn't end with just the extension, it didn't work. Is there an easy way to get this to work? I'm using IIS 7.5.

Comment: This option requires IIS7 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/05/22/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher/

Answer (score 64):

1. Open `web.config` in the directory **where the old pages reside**
2. Then add code for the old location path and new destination as follows:

   ```
    <configuration>
      <location path="services.htm">
        <system.webServer>
          <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://example.com/services" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
      </location>
      <location path="products.htm">
        <system.webServer>
          <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://example.com/products" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
      </location>
    </configuration>
   ```

You may add as many location paths as necessary.

Comment: I like the IIS URL Rewrite Module 2.0 (http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) a lot to these kind of rewrites.

Comment: @mug4n Do you need to keep the old pages (services.htm) in place for this to work or can you completely remove then from your project?

Comment: yes it does work with aspx files. See here for sample codes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325831/asp-net-httpredirect-redirect-all-pages-except-one

Comment: Differences httpRedirect  with URL REWRITE
http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite ?

Comment: What files should be kept in the "old" application in IIS in order for Redirection to keep working. My app is kind of big do I need to keep it as is or can I delete binaries etc?

Answer (score 29):

You probably want to look at something like [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) to rewrite URLs to more user friendly ones rather than using a simple `httpRedirect`. You could then make a rule like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Rewrite to Category">
        <match url="^Category/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="category.aspx?cid={R:2}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to do the opposite (make category.aspx?cid=1234 redirect to category/categoryname/1234). Would it be the same thing? And what does the {R:2} do?

Comment: @PearBerry I know this is late, but yes you could do that in a similar manner.  `{R:2}` refers to the second capture group (`([_0-9a-z-]+)`) and takes whatever was captured there and puts it after the equals sign in the rewritten url.

Comment: I had similar situation, but just stop the request for certain fail. This answer works for me:
 `<rule enabled="true" name="Remove Configurations">
          <match ignoreCase="true" url="configs.json"/>
          <action  statusCode="404" type="AbortRequest" />
        </rule>`

Comment: What if I have 2 parameters to pass ?
How should I pass in url of action type="Redirect"
 <action type="Redirect" url="/Home/givershare?cid={C:1}&uid={C:1}"/>
I tried this but it is not allowing "&"
Please help

Comment: @ShalinJirawla In an XML file you need to escape the ampersand. Use `&amp;`.

Answer (score -2):

In case that you need to add the http redirect in many sites, you could use it as a c# console program:

```
   class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an argument: for example insert-redirect ./web.config http://stackoverflow.com");
            return 1;
        }

        if (args.Length == 3)
        {
            if (args[0].ToLower() == "-insert-redirect")
            {
                var path = args[1];
                var value = args[2];

                if (InsertRedirect(path, value))
                    Console.WriteLine("Redirect added.");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Wrong parameters.");
        return 1;

    }

    static bool InsertRedirect(string path, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.Load(path);

            // This should find the appSettings node (should be only one):
            XmlNode nodeAppSettings = doc.SelectSingleNode("//system.webServer");

            var existNode = nodeAppSettings.SelectSingleNode("httpRedirect");
            if (existNode != null)
                return false;

            // Create new <add> node
            XmlNode nodeNewKey = doc.CreateElement("httpRedirect");

            XmlAttribute attributeEnable = doc.CreateAttribute("enabled");
            XmlAttribute attributeDestination = doc.CreateAttribute("destination");
            //XmlAttribute attributeResponseStatus = doc.CreateAttribute("httpResponseStatus");

            // Assign values to both - the key and the value attributes:

            attributeEnable.Value = "true";
            attributeDestination.Value = value;
            //attributeResponseStatus.Value = "Permanent";

            // Add both attributes to the newly created node:
            nodeNewKey.Attributes.Append(attributeEnable);
            nodeNewKey.Attributes.Append(attributeDestination);
            //nodeNewKey.Attributes.Append(attributeResponseStatus);

            // Add the node under the 
            nodeAppSettings.AppendChild(nodeNewKey);
            doc.Save(path);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception adding redirect: {e.Message}");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definnetly a web config.... Are you aware that IIS does not have to host .NET application to begin with? Thus your C# solution completely misses the question. If the IIS is used to host static content there is no .NET application running.

Comment: I was interested in to give a programmatic way to do the same as a previous solution, just that. Also, a similar approach can be found in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/, I don't think I am missing the question.