# Redirect .aspx webpage using MVC routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have ASP.NE Web Forms application, in which I have ASP.NET MVC area (with razor view engine)

I have a aspx page at this location `project/pages/email.aspx` 
somehow either from crawl agents or some users, they are able to request `http://wwww.mydomain.com/pages/email.aspx?param1=2&param2=3`

I want to redirect such request to "**PageNotFound**"

Below are not options:

1. Remove that page: since that aspx page is used in my application for other purposes.
2. Not interested to do redirect on PageLod event (correct me if that is best way of doing it.)

Interested to know if it is possible this way:

1. Handle though ASP.NET MVC area (which is part of my Web Forms app) RouteConfiguration?
2. ISAPI
3. Web.config / Global.asax

Note: 
 This has to be 301 permanent redirect.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question, I appreciate your comments for downvoting.

Comment: It's a good question +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the web.config by following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10400010/412451

In your case it would look like

```
<configuration>
  <location path="email.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://domain.com/PageNotFound.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Alternatively you might look at the [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) in IIS.

Comment: in my case, I want to redirect only if the request is made from MVC areas but not if it is from Main app. SO should I create a WEb.config in my ASP.NET MVC areas folder and add this httpRedirect there?