# Redirect default pages to homepage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website www.example.com and I want that for the following pages

www.example.com/index.html

www.example.com/index.htm

www.example.com/default.html

www.example.com/default.htm

should redirect to www.example.com. Right now we get 404.

Is there a way other than doing it with bunch of if statements in Global.ascx.cs, OnError() event?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399932/setting-up-redirect-in-web-config-file

Comment: or [URL ReWriting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)