# Url Rewrite with 2 different url bindings

Tags: .net, url, iis, url-rewriting

I have a site set up in IIS that is bound to 2 different urls, that require different languages.  What I want to do is when a user lands on myurl1.com I want to redirect to myurl1.com/en-US and when a user lands on myurl2.com I want to redirect to myurl2.com/es-ES.

Here is my attempt, but is not currently working :

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to en-US locale" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^myurl1.com$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://myurl1.com/en-US" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myurl1.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect to es-ES locale" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^myurl2.com$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://myurl2.com/es-ES" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myurl2.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

I am not familiar with the url rewrite syntax, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: user517406, hope you have resolved the issue, refer the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP_HOST** Server variable will not return the protocols like **http** or **https**

So remove **http://** from **url** attribute of **Action** node. This should work

Try this,

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to en-US locale" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^myurl1.com$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="myurl1.com/en-US" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myurl1.com$" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to es-ES locale" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^myurl2.com$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="myurl2.com/es-ES" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myurl2.com$" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

More information can be found at http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

Answer (score 0):

Please look at here your sample is not a urlrewrite it is just a redirection and i think this may help you:
[Setting up redirect in web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399932/setting-up-redirect-in-web-config-file)