# URL rewriting from Apache (.htaccess) to IIS issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis

I have been working on Php application with Rest Api in Apache environment, which requires URL rewriting, so i have used .htaccess file for writing the rules, which works well in Apache.

Now, i want to use same Php application with Rest Api in IIS enironment, and found that .htaccess is not working in IIS, because it uses different syntax or Method to write the same rules in web.config.

Need assistance, in converting the given rules in IIS environment.

Following are the rules which works fine in apache environment,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

web.config (using online converter from .htaccess):

```
<rule name="rule 1q" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/api.php?x={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2q" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/api.php"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 3q" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/api.php"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 4q" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^"  />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399932/setting-up-redirect-in-web-config-file ,  http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite and  http://www.htaccesstowebconfig.com/

Comment: @yosefh, thanks. IIS has URL Rewrite. And I did convert my .htaccess file to web.config. But IIS throughs error as follows as "Configuration file not well formed XML".

Comment: Include your XML in the question

Comment: <rule name="rule 1x" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/api.php?x={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2x" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/api.php"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 3x" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/api.php"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>

Comment: Balance code: 
<rule name="rule 4x" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^"  />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>

Comment: IIS shows this - The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that <domain>\<computer_name>$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.

Comment: @yosefh, added XML code

Comment: The XML looks ok to me. Maybe its missing some needed surrounding tag? I don't know enough about IIS, sorry man. But you can check out this forum post http://forums.iis.net/t/1148262.aspx?Cannot+verfy+access+to+path

Comment: @yosefh, thanks for this much help buddy :)

Comment: No problem, if you find the answer on your own, you should definitely add the answer below so people with your same issue can solve it.

Comment: @yosefh, sure, I will.

Answer (score 0):

Your web.config XML snippet lacks a lot of XML.

There is no supprise IIS URLRewrite doesn't support all settings an .htaccess does. For instance `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s`, so you have to comment them out before converting. Furthermore, you can use IIS Manager to import the .htaccess to [convert .htaccess to web.config](https://www.saotn.org/convert-apache-htaccess-iis-web-config/).

The reason I'm posting this as an answer is because I just did this converting for you -and need some reply space :)

Here is the .htaccess, with two lines commented out:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And the converted URLRewrite rules in web.config:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!--#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s-->
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php?x={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <!--
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    completely disabled, does nothing important anymore since 
    %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s is not supported on IIS
    <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    -->
    <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This may require some further tweaking, see iis.net for more information.