# IIS URL redirect directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-routing, http-redirect

I am having an issue using IIS URl redirect module.
Trying to redirect from www.site.com/directory1/default.aspx
to www.site.com/directory2/default.aspx

So any request to directory1 needs to go to directory 2. I am going to be disabling the application at directory 1
Any ideas?
Currently i have the below, but does not work.

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <remove name="Portal Test Redirect" />
                <rule name="Portal Test Redirect" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*directory1/*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions />
                    <serverVariables />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/directory2/{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your rule as below

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>            
        <rule name="Portal Test Redirect">
            <match url="(.*)(directory1)(.*)" patternSyntax="ECMAScript"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}directory2{R:3}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Would this deal with query string parameters as well? All i need is the directory to change

Comment: Yes it should be but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Are you still running into issues?

Comment: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: That's nothing to do with URL Rewrite rule. Looks like you are adding a section in child web.config which is not allowed there. Can you confirm where are you adding the rule and which section you are getting this error for ?

Answer (score 0):

1.Open web.config in the directory where the old pages reside
2.Then add code for the old location path and new destination as follows:

```html
<configuration>
  <location path="services.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://domain.com/services" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="products.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://domain.com/products" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Try above. Refered from [Setting up redirect in web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399932/setting-up-redirect-in-web-config-file)