# looking for a way to redirect everything under a path in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, umbraco7

I'm looking for a way to redirect user when they want to access for example
www.domainname.com/products/car/volvo/car1
to
www.domainname.com/products/
i'm using umbraco to build the site

Comment: You could use the umbracoUrlAlias property to create an alias or use rewrites in the web.config, but where should www.domainname.com/products/car/volvo/car2 redirect to?

Comment: it would redirect to www.domainname.com/products/

im making an ajax based app only on the product page

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't be using a template on the car document, but instead let the products node template handle it using a custom api controller.

Comment: if i use custome api controller, admin cant change template from umbraco cms

Comment: That's true, you can probably use partialviews or (depending on the frontend framework you're using) some other form of templating for that. Changing the routing of Umbraco for this isn't really recommended to achieve this. If you do want to call the page using ajax, you can even use the alttemplate on the car node to show an alternative view in case the page is called from ajax. This will benefit seo as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than handling such requests from the application's web.config, you could have the web server (IIS) redirect the requests. Please refer below link on how you may do so.

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect?showTreeNavigation=true

Comment: I have specifically said from web config.

Comment: Why don't you try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399932/setting-up-redirect-in-web-config-file