# Redirecting page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

If I try accessing a certain page (e.g., `file.html`) via its URL, I get redirected (e.g., to `enroll.html`). But if I go through `enroll.html` I won't get redirected.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: What is involved in the enrollment process? I would base the redirection on whether the user is authenticated, logged in, etc. Once they are "enrolled", they can access `file.html`.

Comment: Basic logic on the server if the user is able to access it or not. Mark if they were on enroll.html and if it is in their session, that let them see it. If not, redirect them away.

Comment: yeah truth is I'm trying to quickly skip the session id part cus this is kinda like a demo and yeah the enroll part is for newsletter subscription XD.

Comment: you can set up web.config https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399932/setting-up-redirect-in-web-config-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate the referer with javascript (`document.referrer`) or with php (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`)

```
if(document.referrer != 'http:// - - - /enroll.html')
    window.location.replace("http:// - - - /enroll.html")

if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'http:// - - - /enroll.html')
    header('Location: http:// - - - /enroll.html');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Dont rely solely on this, as it can be easily faked.

Comment: it keeps redirecting me as if the referer is always invalid

Comment: I had a typo in `document.referrer`, also you can print it, to make sure it has the value you are expecting. `console.log(document.referrer)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.referrer` to achieve this with JS.

Example:

```
function func() {
    if (document.referrer == "whatever page") {
        //TODO enter code
    } else {
        window.location = "whatever page";
}
```