# Having trouble with web.config redirect; 500 internal server error

Tags: redirect, web-config

I've created a new website and some old links don't work so I want to redirect those links to my new homepage with anchor tags. I have tried so many code snippets but nothing is working. Can anyone see what I've done wrong (I'm not a programmer) thanks! -

I just get:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Here is my code:

```
<location path="page_contact.html">
  <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html#contact" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
  </system.webServer>
</location>

<location path="portfolio.html">
  <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html#portfolio" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: <location path="page_contact.html">
<system.webServer>
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.example.com/index.html#contact" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
</system.webServer>
</location>

<location path="portfolio.html">
<system.webServer>
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.example.com/index.html#portfolio" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
</system.webServer>
</location>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up redirect in web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399932/setting-up-redirect-in-web-config-file)