# Can i host multiple pages in a project on different domains?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, subdomain

I'm here with another question. I was just wondering if we have a asp.net core web application and in that we have a Teacher controller and a student controller. If we want to host the pages like teacher.domain.com or student.domain.com ?
Like many on many sites  i have seen if there is a completely different functionality it will be on separate domain. I know we can host different project on different subdomains.
Might be a silly question to ask but just want to know if there is any workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

Make sure you apply the appropriate redirect rules in web.config. regex match each domain and redirect to the appropriate controller . 
[Setting up redirect in web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399932/setting-up-redirect-in-web-config-file).

Or easier approach is to have your Home/Index redirect to the appropriate controller, but that won't save you in case someone types a url like 
teacher.domain.com/AStudentController.

Then set your dns to the same application and let your app handle proper redirection.

Additionally you might find "MVC Areas" useful for your scenario. 
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/area-in-asp.net-mvc

One last concern in case your websites are public facing, you have also to take care about indexing.

You don't want google to index teacher content on the student.domain.com site.
You can take care of that with canonical urls , proper redirects, and dynamic robot.txt file serving.