# Redirect one vb.net page only?

Tags: asp.net, redirect

In this link here: [ASP.NET httpRedirect : redirect all pages except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325831/asp-net-httpredirect-redirect-all-pages-except-one)

the poster asks how to redirect all pages except one. How would I do the opposite and only redirect one page, please? I have a Web contact form that is not redirecting to 'thankyou.aspx' after the user presses 'Send' (the form field data disappears but the form remains in place (contact.aspx remains in the address bar when it should redirect to thankyou.aspx).

There are no error messages and the SMTP code works, but it seems I may have a server 301 error on that contact.aspx page.

Thank you.

Comment: I have done that, Olivier:

Protected Sub contact_submitted_Click, etc

SMTP code here

Dim target = String.Format("~/thankyou.aspx?your_name={0}", yourname)

Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/thankyou.aspx?your_name={0}", yourname), True)

But as I say, the code is not being processed on account of a 301 error, so when 'Send' is clicked the 'contact.aspx' page remains and never gets 
to the 'thankyou.aspx' page.

I need to force the browser to go to 'thankyou.aspx' after 'Send' is clicked, but not sure how to do it. In Web.config?

Comment: Can you update your question, and post the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done these things in the past.

In your contact form you have a button.

```
<asp:button id="btnSend" runat="server" OnSubmit="Send_Click"></button>
```

Then in your code behind

```
public void Send_Click(Object o, EventArgs e) {

// code to send the email

Response.Redirect("/thankyou.aspx");

}
```

Comment: I have done that, Olivier: Protected Sub contact_submitted_Click, etc SMTP code here Dim target = String.Format("~/thankyou.aspx?your_name={0}", yourname) Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/thankyou.aspx?your_name={0}", yourname), True) But as I say, the code is not being processed on account of a 301 error, so when 'Send' is clicked the 'contact.aspx' page remains and never gets to the 'thankyou.aspx' page. I need to force the browser to go to 'thankyou.aspx' after 'Send' is clicked, but not sure how to do it. In Web.config?