# Website web.config > Is it possible to redirect an incorrect subdomain to a certain page?

Tags: redirect, web-config, subdomain

Is it possible to redirect an incorrect subdomain (A non-existant subdomain) to a certain page (Custom error page)?

*EDIT: Using a web.config file*

For example, if I typed http://foo.squishling.co.uk/ it would redirect to something like http://squishling.co.uk/errors/incorrect_subdomain.html/, as http://foo.squishling.co.uk/ isn't a correct subdomain.

I haven't seen any code that does this, so is it possible?
*EDIT: If it isn't possible, please say so*

Thanks in advance,
~ Squishling

*EDIT: If this is possible, a possible way of doing it would be when the server recieves a request for the incorrect subdomain, just trick the request into requesting an error page*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here's how with IIS 10 + UrlRewrite 2.1.

For example's purposes let's assume I have:

- A valid domain/port `good.localhost:81`
- my custom error file @ `/error.txt`

#### Step 1: Set up site bindings to accept requests for sub domains

IIS manager -> web site context menu -> "Edit Bindings.."
Edit accepted host name to accept `*.<yourDomain>`. For the example case:
[image]

Detailed steps can be found from documentation page ["Wildcard Host Header Support"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support#step-by-step-instructions).

Now site should respond to both `http://good.localhost:81` as well as `http://bad.localhost:81`.

#### Step2: install Url rewrite module

You can find URL rewrite module installer from here:
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

#### Step3: configure redirect rule

While you could use IIS MAnager's GUI for this, you could as well just handwrite something like this to your web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="DirectBadSubdomainsRule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^good\.localhost:81" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://good.localhost:81/error.txt" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can use the power of regex to determine which subdomains are valid and which ones are not. Also you can decide exactly which redirection code you want. The example above uses Temporary redirect (HTTP307).

There's a lot of documentation in here: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

#### Testing

Non-good domain should now return redirection response:

1. http://bad.localhost:81/correct.txt -> HTTP307
2. http://good.localhost:81/error.txt -> HTTP200

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.
Here's a minimal `nginx` configuration doing this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        rewrite ^.*$ http://squishling.co.uk/errors/incorrect_subdomain.html redirect;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name squishling.co.uk;

    location / {
        echo some page;
    }

    location /errors/incorrect_subdomain.html {
        echo incorrect subdomain error;
    }
}
```

This is how to run it:

1. `mkdir conf.d`
2. put the config file above into `conf.d/main.conf`
3. `docker run -p80:80 -v ~/work/test/subreq/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d openresty/openresty:alpine`

#### testing

*squishling.co.uk* and *foo.squishling.co.uk* are overridden in my `/etc/hosts` so they direct to my localhost

```
curl -D - http://squishling.co.uk
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty/1.13.6.1
Date: Tue, 06 Feb 2018 18:49:25 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

some page
```

Now trying the wrong domain

```
curl -D - http://foo.squishling.co.uk
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: openresty/1.13.6.1
Date: Tue, 06 Feb 2018 18:49:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 167
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://squishling.co.uk/errors/incorrect_subdomain.html

<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.13.6.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Or the same following the redirection:

```
curl -L -D - http://foo.squishling.co.uk
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: openresty/1.13.6.1
Date: Tue, 06 Feb 2018 18:50:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 167
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://squishling.co.uk/errors/incorrect_subdomain.html

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty/1.13.6.1
Date: Tue, 06 Feb 2018 18:50:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

incorrect subdomain error
```

So the main idea is that you define the `default` server configuration that would intercept all the domains besides those having individual configurations. The same can be accomplished in other web servers too

Comment: Question tag `web-config` suggests the OP is interested a solution for IIS, not nginx.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. Reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10662732/7877099

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://squishling.co.uk/errors/" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
    <location path="incorrect_subdomain.html">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="false" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.